# Global optimisation algorithm - without toolbox

Tags: matlab, optimization

I want to find the global maximum/minimum of a function (not an analytical one, I also assume a lot of discontinuities).
I wanted to use Simulated Annealing or other approaches, but I sadly cannot use the Global Optimisation Toolbox (too expensive). Does anyone know where I can find costumly written Code for global optimisation, it does not have to be sim.annealing...anything that works is good.
My function has three real Parameters, whereas two of them are bfrom [0 a] (with 'a' being real and with a value  ~1000) and the last one is Bound from [0 360] (degrees).

The programming language is matlab, I will update my problem with details later!

Thanks in Advance!
Martin

Comment: Please specify in the tags, or at least in the question, the context like the programming language or tool you are using and referring to (MATLAB?).